# Google Drive not retrieving folders

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-drive-api

I have this code:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');

// Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: './credentials.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
});

// Create a new instance of the Drive API
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

async function listFolders() {
  try {
    const response = await drive.files.list({
      q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false",
      fields: 'files(id, name)',
      orderBy: 'name'
    });

    const folders = response.data.files;
    if (folders.length) {
      console.log('Folders:');
      folders.forEach(folder => {
        console.log(`${folder.name} (${folder.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No folders found.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error listing folders:', error.message);
  }
}

listFolders();
```

which obviously is going to fetch the folders that exists in "My Drive" but even if the folders existed, the logs says otherwise: "No folders found."

Any thoughts?

I use service account for this one but still i can't make it work and yes the credentials are there in my .json file

Comment: troubleshooting tip .. what is the value of `response`? `response.data` ? and `response.data.files`?

Comment: From your `const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({,,,})`, I guess that you might be using the service account. Values `private_key` and `client_email` are included in `credentials.json`? If my understanding is correct, the drive of the service account is different from your drive of your account. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. How about this? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: response.data is { files: [] } but its not the problem here, the problem was when i open the responseurl they sent to me, it says "The request is missing a valid API key." and status of "Permission Denied"

Comment: You're right Tanaike, im using service account and have those credentials you've mentioned in my .json file... idk what you meant by "drive of the service account is different from your drive of my account", if you can explain this to me, i would be glad.